# '[object HTMLLIElement]' when pushing one array into another

Tags: jquery, arrays, append, push

Suppose I have a dynamically created list items

```
<li>item1</li>
<li>item2</li>
<li>item3</li>
<li>item4</li>
```

All these items are pushed into an array `var itemArray= [];`

The problem is I have another array

```
var array2= [];
```

of dynamically created 'li' pushed into itemArray using `itemArray.push(array2)`

whenever I append it using the following code

```
$('<ul/>', {

   html: itemArray.join('')
}).appendTo('#left_div');
```

I get the following display

```
[object HTMLLIElement]
```

for the items from array2

Comment: do you mean `var itemArray = [];`? `{}` denotes an object literal, `[]` denotes an *array* literal. you can't `.push()` an object, but you can push an array. have you taken a look at your console errors?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. Sorry, I meant var itemArray = []; I do not have any console errors. But instead of values from itemArray, I get [object HTMLLIElement].

Answer (score 1):

When you call `itemArray.join('')`, you implicitly cast all the elements to strings using their `toString()` method. As you discovered, this just returns `[object HTMLLIElement]`.

What you should do is just use `.append(itemArray)`, which does allow for an array of DOM elements:

```
$('<ul/>', {}).append(itemArray).appendTo('#left_div');
```

Also, it looks like you might be appending `array2` wrong. You probably want to use `concat()` instead, which allows for merging two arrays. What's happening right now makes it look like `[<li>,<li>,<li>,[<li>,<li>,<li>]]`, not a single flat array:

```
itemArray = itemArray.concat(array2);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `.push()` an array into another array, it doesn't append the one array to the end of the other the way you are thinking. The output of your `itemArr.push(array2);` method would look something like this:

```
0: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
1: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
2: Array[2]
```

.. notice the entire `array2` is added as an item in `itemArray`...

What you are looking for is [`$.merge()`:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

```
$.merge(itemArray, array2);
```

Then, finally, assuming your list items are added to your arrays, not as strings, but as dynamically rendered elements (as you said) you should be able to simply `.append()` the merged array to the `<ul>` (or dynamically generated ul).

Example:

```js
// setup: dummy list item arrays
var li = $('<li>'),
    item1 = li.clone().append('item1'),
    item2 = li.clone().append('item2');

var li2 = $('<li>'),
    item3 = li2.clone().append('item3'),
    item4 = li2.clone().append('item4');

var arr1 = [];
arr1.push(item1);
arr1.push(item2);

var arr2 = [];
arr2.push(item3);
arr2.push(item4);


// merge!
$.merge(arr1, arr2);


// create a ul element dynamically
var ul = $('<ul>');

// add your items:
ul.append(arr1);

// render the ul
$('body').append(ul);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```